# How do I use Group Policy to sync client time in an Active Directory domain with an external NTP server and not the domain controller?

Tags: windows, active-directory, samba, ntp, samba4

I have an Active Directory domain, with a domain controller running on Samba on Linux.

I noticed that my Windows clients are having clock drift. I think this is because they really want the domain controller to offer a time synchronization service. But since I never set up a time server on the domain controller, that isn't happening.

Now, Samba doesn't seem to include a time server feature, and I would rather not add another service to the things I need to maintain. I am perfectly happy with everyone in the domain, including the DC, individually syncing up with `time.windows.com`. But if I go in the default domain policy or in `gpedit.msc` on an individual client and make the `Configure Windows NTP Client` and `Enable Windows NTP Client` objects, they don't seem to take effect, and my client's time source stays stuck at "Local CMOS Clock".

**How can I configure Group Policy in an Active Directory domain to make clients get their time directly from an Internet NTP server, instead of from a domain controller?**

I found [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/763290/49409) that gives a command line procedure that it claims lets you escape the domain time hierarchy for an individual host, but I am interested in doing it for all the clients in the domain (and also the DC, though that is Samba and unlikely to obey the policy).

Comment: https://theitbros.com/configure-ntp-time-sync-group-policy/

Comment: All domain controllers advertise as a time server by default. It doesn't need to be configured. If you want to know why it is using the local clock, you should enable time service verbose logging.

Comment: @GregAskew Samba *advertises* as a time server, but doesn't actually *implement* an NTP daemon, so it does not actually synchronize time for clients out of the box.

Comment: @joeqwerty I attempted to follow the "Configure Client Time Sync Settings Using GPO" part of that page. It did not seem to work for me.

Comment: @interfect: domain controllers don't advertise as NTP servers by default. It uses RPC. 99.9999% of Windows clients use RPC for time synchronization by default.